# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_dateFns.default.format') I'm getting an error while coding the calendar using expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o51bMu9egsZ3QELzu-t0jVF0rW9Rvkr2?usp=sharing

I'm getting an error while coding the calendar using expo

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post your code as text? Also see [ask]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o51bMu9egsZ3QELzu-t0jVF0rW9Rvkr2?usp=sharing

Comment: you can go to my drive to see it because i don't have permission to post pictures

Comment: import dateFns from 'date-fns';

const format = (date = new Date()) => dateFns.format(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

const getMarkedDates = (baseDate, appointments) => {
  const markedDates = {};

  markedDates[format(baseDate)] = { selected: true };

  appointments.forEach((appointment) => {
    const formattedDate = format(new Date(appointment.date));
    markedDates[formattedDate] = {
      ...markedDates[formattedDate],
      marked: true,
    };
  });

  return markedDates;
};